# Fock operator invariance under unitary transformation

Tags: quantum-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I know how to show that the Coulomb operator of the Fock operator is invariant under a unitary transformation of the orbitals, as on page 121 of Szabo and Ostlund, but the indices in my proof for the exchange operator are just not working.  What might I be missing?
I have

\begin{align}
\sum_i\hat{K}_i'(1) &=\sum_i\int dr_2\chi_i'^*(2)\chi_j'(2)/r_{12} \\
 &=\sum_i\int dr_2\sum_kU_{ki}^*\chi_k^*(2)\sum_lU_{lj}\chi_l(2)/r_{12}\\
 &=\sum_{ikl}\int dr_2U_{ki}^*U_{lj}\chi_k^*(2)\chi_l(2)/r_{12}\\
 &=\sum_{i}\int dr_2\chi_i^*(2)\chi_i(2)/r_{12}\\
 &\neq\sum_{i}\int dr_2\chi_i^*(2)\chi_j(2)/r_{12}.
\end{align}

Comment: How are you contracting $U_{ki}^* U_{lj}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exchange operator is not a operator by itself, it is only defined with the orbital it is working on: 
$%
\newcommand{\ll}{\left\langle}\newcommand{\rr}{\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\lb}{\left|}\newcommand{\rb}{\right|}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$
$$\begin{align}
  && \op{F}_i &= \op{H}^\mathrm{c} + \sum_j (\op{J}_j - \op{K}_j),\\
\text{with}&& 
     \op{J}_j\lb \phi_i\rr &=
       \ll \phi_j(\op{x}_1) \rb r_{12}^{-1} 
       \lb \phi_j(\op{x}_1) \rr \lb \phi_i(\op{x}_2) \rr,\\
\text{and}&&
     \op{K}_j\lb \phi_i\rr &=
       \ll \phi_j(\op{x}_1) \rb r_{12}^{-1} 
       \lb \phi_i(\op{x}_1) \rr \lb \phi_j(\op{x}_2) \rr.
\end{align}$$

While in the Coulomb operator case the $\lb \phi_i\rr$ doesn't do anything, so you can take it through the proof as a constant:<sup>*</sup>
\begin{align}
  \sum_j\op{J}_j\lb \phi_i\rr 
  &= \sum_j 
     \ll \phi_j(\op{x}_1) \rb r_{12}^{-1} 
     \lb \phi_j(\op{x}_1) \rr \lb \phi_i(\op{x}_2) \rr\\
  &= \sum_k \sum_l \sum_j U_{kj}^*U_{lj}
     \ll \phi_k(\op{x}_1) \rb r_{12}^{-1} 
     \lb \phi_l(\op{x}_1) \rr \lb \phi_i(\op{x}_2) \rr\\
  &= \sum_k \sum_l \delta_{kl}
     \ll \phi_k(\op{x}_1) \rb r_{12}^{-1} 
     \lb \phi_l(\op{x}_1) \rr \lb \phi_i(\op{x}_2) \rr\\
  &= \sum_k 
     \ll \phi_k(\op{x}_1) \rb r_{12}^{-1} 
     \lb \phi_k(\op{x}_1) \rr \lb \phi_i(\op{x}_2) \rr\\
  &= \sum_k \op{J}_k \lb \phi_i\rr
\end{align}

That is not the case in the Exchange operator, as it switches the orbitals:
\begin{align}
  \sum_j\op{K}_j\lb \phi_i\rr 
  &= \sum_j 
     \ll \phi_j(\op{x}_1) \rb r_{12}^{-1} 
     \lb \phi_i(\op{x}_1) \rr \lb \phi_j(\op{x}_2) \rr\\
  &= \sum_k \sum_l \sum_j U_{kj}^*U_{lj}
     \ll \phi_k(\op{x}_1) \rb r_{12}^{-1} 
     \lb \phi_i(\op{x}_1) \rr \lb \phi_l(\op{x}_2) \rr\\
  &= \sum_k \sum_l \delta_{kl}
     \ll \phi_k(\op{x}_1) \rb r_{12}^{-1} 
     \lb \phi_i(\op{x}_1) \rr \lb \phi_l(\op{x}_2) \rr\\
  &= \sum_k 
     \ll \phi_k(\op{x}_1) \rb r_{12}^{-1} 
     \lb \phi_i(\op{x}_1) \rr \lb \phi_k(\op{x}_2) \rr\\
  &= \sum_k \op{K}_k \lb \phi_i\rr
\end{align}

---

<sup>*</sup> Let 
$$
\mathbb{U}=\left(\begin{matrix}
  U_{11} & U_{12} & \dots \\
  U_{21} & U_{22} & \dots \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\\
  \end{matrix}\right);
\mathbb{U}^\dagger\mathbb{U}=\mathbb{E}
\implies U_{ij}^* U_{kl}= \delta_{ij} = \begin{cases}
   1; & i = j = k = l \\ 0; & i \neq j \dots\\ \end{cases}
.$$